TinyMCE: Referer header is missing error in asp.net mvc
I created an account in TinyMCE and got the API key.
after that, I added Localhost in my approved Domain and my script looks like below
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/APIKey/tinymce/7/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

I went to this URL and downloaded the script to use it locally in my asp.net MVC application
after that, it looks like below
but I am getting the below error ->

We’re unable to check your domain because the referer header is
missing.
Ensure your referer header is present, so we can then customize your
editor experience.
Read to learn more:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/cloud-troubleshooting/
↓↓↓↓↓ ATTENTION ADMINS ↓↓↓↓↓ Please include these details in Tiny
Cloud support requests. Resolved API key: no-origin Editor read-only?:
no Origin: http://localhost:32695 Tiny Cloud entry URL:
http://localhost:32695/Content/plugins/TinyMCE/tinymce.min.js ↑↑↑↑↑
---------------- ↑↑↑↑↑ I @ tinymce.min.js:18 value @ tinymce.min.js:18 tcsl @ tinymce.min.js:32 (anonymous) @ tinymce.min.js:33Understand
this warning

Even after providing the API key and approving the domain why I am getting the above error?

Your import method has some problem,you can try to  install  TinyMCE package Following the official tutorial ：
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dotnet-projects/
1.install the Ti nyMCE  package to the project

2. Import tinymce.js  in _layout.cshtml:
 <script src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

3.It works like this:

